# Ubuntu One Connection failed

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-one

I have installed Ubuntu 10.10. Then I try to connect Ubuntu One. I can enter my login, but in the preferences Name and E-Mail are "unknown".

```
  u1sdtool --status
  State: AUTH_FAILED
    connection: With User With Network
    description: auth failed
    is_connected: False
    is_error: True
    is_online: False
    queues: IDLE
```

I tryed also to remove the computers on https://one.ubuntu.com/account/machines/ but "Something has gone wrong"

This also does not help

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Status#General+and+Accounts

Soemthing goes terribly wrong. Any idea?

Comment: can you log in online?

Comment: I had Problems for a few hours. But even if the online page works I could'nt connect a new machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you tried the steps listed on the status page, were you prompted to add your computer to Ubuntu One again? You should have been.

If you're getting a 500 error when going to the https://one.ubuntu.com/account/machines/ it may have been intermittent. If you're still getting the error, please send a direct support request to the Ubuntu One team at: https://one.ubuntu.com/support/contact

Comment: I send a message to the support yesterday. Today its working again. I had lots of Machines in my account from all the trys to connect.